# The size of tensor a (100) must match the size of tensor b (64) at non-singleton dimension 2"

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to implement a simple linear network.

The input tensor size is (B,3,64,64)

My network is defined like this.

```
    tensorSize = x.size()
    input = tensorSize[0] * tensorSize[1] * tensorSize[2]
    self.linear_one = torch.nn.Linear(64, input)
    self.linear_two = torch.nn.Linear(input, 32)
    self.linear_output = torch.nn.Linear(32, 6)
    self.layer_in = self.linear_one(x)
    self.layer_in_two = self.linear_two(self.layer_in)
    self.layer_out = self.linear_output(self.layer_in_two)
```

My output is size (B,3,64,6) but it needs to be (B,6)

Why is my network not outputting the correct results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using linear layers with fixed input and output sizes.

Flatten the input tensor before passing it through the linear layers.

```
# Flatten dimensions (B, 3, 64, 64) to (B, 3*64*64)
x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
```